# android hide folder to sd card and share the image inside the hidden folder

Tags: android

i want to hide a folder created on my external storage the get the path of the hidden folder to share data found inside the hidden folder. how can i achieve this. what i have done since now.

```
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/mdata/");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
```

the sharing

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/mdata/"+path));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide folder in Android or any Linux based system just add . as prefix to folder or file name.

However if you mount your SD card on Windows machine then these folders will be visible, with the . in front of the folder name, as a normal folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the folder from most scans etc. by prefixing it with a `.`. This will make it a UNIX hidden folder.

However, users can still browse it with a file manager or on their computer, and apps can still access it if they want to.

If you want your data completely hidden from other apps, store it on a private server. Even the internal storage can be read with root, and the external storage can be read by any app with the permission to do so.